# Distance bound for convex combination of inputs

Tags: probability-theory

Let $f$ be a function of 2 variables.  Consider $f\colon X \times Y \rightarrow Z$.
Let $P_i$ (for $i=1,\ldots,n$) be $n$ probability distributions on $X$, and let $Q$ be a distribution on $Z$.

We know that if we choose $X$ according to any of the $P_i$ (the distribution on $Y$ is fixed throughout), $f_{x \leftarrow P_i}(X,Y)$ is at most $\epsilon$-away from $Q$ (say in $L_1$ norm).
Does the statement hold when $X$ is chosen according to some convex combination of $P_i$?

My guess is it should, with an argument similar to max should be greater than the average (convex combination), but I am unable to prove it formally.

Note that $f$ need not be linear in $X$.

Comment: You have a notational issue, in that you use $X$ both as a set that is the domain of some random variable and to represent that random variable. Can you prove any special cases, such as where the random variable $Y$ is a constant, or where $X=\{0,1\},Y=\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @D.W. Yes. I think. Consider Y to be constant. In that case, f can be treated as a function of a single variable $x$. Then $f(X)$ is just a convex combination of the corresponding distributions obtained from individual $P_i$. The rest follows by elementary properties of $L_1$ norm.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R_i$ be the distribution of $f(X,Y)$ when $X \sim P_i$, and let $R$ be the distribution when $X$ is chosen to some mixture of the $P_i$, say $X \sim P_i$ with probability $\alpha_i$. Then $R$ is a mixture of the $R_i$, with the same coefficients $\alpha_i$.

We are given that for each $i$, $\|R_i - Z\|_1 \leq \epsilon$. Therefore
$$
\|R-Z\|_1 = \left\|\sum_i \alpha_i (R_i - Z)\right\|_1 \stackrel{(\ast)}\leq \sum_i \alpha_i \|R_i - Z\|_1 \leq \epsilon,
$$
using the triangle inequality and linearity at the highlighted step.